# Using external html templates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I have a situation where I need to insert a block of code when somebody clicks something - I don't really need to do any server side processing for this so doing it via JS would be ideal.

In saying that I'm not sure what the best way to handle templates in JS would be - that is having a block of code which you want to make replacements in with variables.

Yes I could include the actual HTML in the same JS file, but that would be rather messy and I want to avoid that.

What is generally the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you done a quick Google search for "javascript template"?

Comment: @Pointy Of course. Found stuff about underscore, but that seemed like overkill.

Comment: Smallest one I know of is [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT). Super flexible.

Comment: You should try backbone js where you can use html templates.

Comment: I don't think there is a "best way" to do it, otherwise there wouldn't be a ba-jillion different plugins for it.

Comment: You should read [link](http://codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/how-to-use-templates-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/)

Comment: Thanks for the links!